# Scheduled Package SQL agent job

Tags: ssis, scheduled-tasks, sql-agent

I have a SSIS package designed to download all the FTP files then insert them into the database. Current I m using the 2014 SQL express version I want to understand how the SQL agents works. So my question is If I have a the SQL agent schedule to run the package everyday and let say if i get a error message from the package due to network drive issues. Will the package still keep running everyday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will run on the next scheduled run after any failure, but if you haven't handled the issue causing the failure by then (for instance if you are our of space on the server and haven't fixed that since the previous day), it may still fail or run but cause a data integrity issue because the previous file was not run. Depending on how the SSIS package is written and if you are receiving a full file or a partial file (commonly called a delta as it contains only records changed since the last file, these must always be processed in order) you may need manual intervention after a failure of any nature.